# R string for calculating signature

Tags: r, string, hash

Is there any less complicated solution for the following task?

For working with API I need to calculate signature using the formula below.
Problem comes from double quotes in request body, they stored as `\"` not `"`.

Code below generate text `1570702210SoMeF@ke123456[{ "id": "123", "title": "foo", "version": "2019-10-10 10:10:10  } ]}SoMeF@ke123456` and correct hash is `"b6e783309e9d6f8ee47647373a9f6086020b3af8"` by http://www.sha1-online.com/

Signature formula: 
hex( sha1({GMT_UNIXTIME} + {API_SECRET} + {CONTENT} + {API_SECRET}) ), where

- hex() - function which convert binary data into hexadecimal format
- sha1() - standard hash-function SHA-1, must return binary data
- - text string concatenation
- {API_SECRET} - a secret key which is issued together with login {API_LOGIN}
- {CONTENT} - request body

Following code gives incorrect signature "c7a7ecbb0fd2d6eebfb378bdd061ea88d9fb2f69".

```
 library(stringr)
 library(lubridate)
 library(digest)


API_SECRET <- 'SoMeF@ke123456'
mstime <- ymd_hms('2019-10-10 10:10:10')
my_id <- 123
title1 <- 'foo'

request_body_json <- paste0('[{ "id": "', my_id,'", "title": "', title1, '", "version": "', mstime, '  } ]}')

rbj1 <- paste0(round(as.numeric(mstime)), API_SECRET, request_body_json, API_SECRET)

signature <- digest(rbj1, algo = "sha1")
```

I see a workaround with saving string to file with `cat()` function and calculate signature from file, that gives correct signature "b6e783309e9d6f8ee47647373a9f6086020b3af8"

```
cat(paste0(round(as.numeric(mstime)), API_SECRET, request_body_json, API_SECRET), file = 'rbj.txt')

signature <- digest('rbj.txt', algo = "sha1", file = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prevent the input being serialized:

```
digest(rbj1, algo = "sha1", serialize = FALSE)

[1] "b6e783309e9d6f8ee47647373a9f6086020b3af8"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I knew that there is clever way.